# same enum class, but different definition depending on condition

Tags: c++, enums

Hi I'm trying to have enum outside of class but inside namespace AND  have them have different definition depending on some condition. How can I achieve this? (C++)

For example something like this

```
namespace fruit  {
    if (season) {
      enum eAvailfruit
      {
        apple,
        banana,
        cNumFruit
      };
    } else {
      enum eAvailfruit
      {
        watermelon,
        grape,
        peach,
        cNumFruit
      };
    }
}
```

Is there a way ??

Comment: I imagine so if `season` is a compile-time constant, but not otherwise.

Comment: What is the scope of the condition, `season`?

Comment: But how will you deal with code that used the enum? For example, if you've got code that mentions `banana` then what will happen when `season` is false?

Comment: `#if` or `#ifdef` with a corresponding `#endif`.

Comment: That all sounds like a baaaad design idea. May be a XY-problem, what are you actually about to solve?

Comment: I would use Fruit as an enum with all possible fruit that you support. And an AvailableFruit as boolean array/map indexed by your Fruit enum.

Comment: yeah I Wasn't sure how to have "season" set. and @Sean all the code that references banana will be also under if (season) throughout the code.

Comment: @user2134081 "all the code that references banana will be also under if (season) throughout the code" That sounds like you are about to have a lot of duplicate code.

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to use the preprocessor:

```
#ifdef SUMMER
enum Fruit {
    // ....
};
#else
enum Fruit {
    // ...
};
#endif
```

and then pass a compile-time constant in whatever way your compiler normally prefers it, for example the `-D` flag in gcc.

Or, on the other hand, don't, because it's a terrible idea. One *slightly* better solution might be the following:

```
enum Season {
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Autumn,
    Winter
};

template <Season S>
struct fruit; // undefined

template <>
struct fruit<Spring>
{
    enum AvailableFruit {
        Banana,
        // etc
    };
};

template <>
struct fruit<Summer>
{
    enum AvailableFruit {
         // etc
    };
};

// etc, specialisations for Autumn and Winter
```

These structs are then fairly similarly to C++11 scoped enums, in that you can refer to (for example) `fruit<Spring>::Banana`, but they're type safe as it's illegal to refer to just plain `Banana`, or even just plain `AvailableFruit`.